# Keras custom loss becomes NaN after a while for regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am trying to use a custom loss function for my model. I am scaling y values previously and in my loss function I inverse scale them.(Using the answer from [scaling back data in customized keras training loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857212/scaling-back-data-in-customized-keras-training-loss-function)) After a random amount of epochs the loss starts to come as NaN also mean_absolute_error val_mean_absolute_error and val_loss are all NaN. Heres my model and custom loss function:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=512, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=256, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
model.add(Dense(units = 2))
model.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss = my_loss_function , metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
model.summary()
```

I have 2 outputs as you can see.

```
def my_loss_function(y_actual, y_predicted):
    
    y_actual = (y_actual - K.constant(y_scaler.min_)) / K.constant(y_scaler.scale_)
    y_predicted = (y_predicted - K.constant(y_scaler.min_)) / K.constant(y_scaler.scale_)
    
    
    a_loss = abs(y_actual[0]-y_predicted[0])*128000
    b_loss = abs(y_actual[1]-y_predicted[1])*27000
    
    loss= tf.math.sqrt(tf.square(a_loss) + tf.square(b_loss))
    return loss
```

y_scaler is used earlier:

```
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
y_scaler.fit(y_data)
y_data=y_scaler.transform(y_data)
y_testdata=y_scaler.transform(y_testdata)
```

Can anyone help?

When I use MSE, MAE etc. it works fine

Comment: Are you sure you don't have NaNs in your dataset?

Comment: @Frightera Yes I replaced all NaN values with 100 before I did anything.

Comment: Also what do you mean by you have 2 outputs? You only one output in the network. And why do you multiply losses with such big numbers, **128000?**

Comment: @Frightera It should be 111000, the 2 outputs I am talking about should be the latitude and longitude and I multiply them by these numbers to find the distance between the prediction and true coordinates in terms of meters. Doesn't my "single" output consist of 2 values?

Comment: Exactly, 1 output with a shape `(2,)`. As I am not sure multiplying with big numbers could cause gradients to explode.

Comment: @Frightera I removed the multipliers to check and after 63 epochs loss becomes NaN again

Comment: Try to use gradient clipping, might help.

Comment: @Frightera Looks like gradient clipping fixed it thank you.

Comment: @Frightera But do you know why it gave NaN even when I was not including multipliers? Exploding gradients should not be an issue no?

Comment: They might have exploded at some point. NaN is because of exploding gradients, mostly.